# Git only add/commit move without adding content change

Tags: git

I have a bunch of files that I moved from one location to another and I changed the content of them (90%+ changes).
The files are properly moved with `git mv` and git also detects it as a rename.

My question is: Is it possible to only add and commit the move without adding the content changes of the files?

I already have all those local changes and don't want to redo everything.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, commit after moving and then change the files

Comment: @UlysseBN yea... that's obvious. Only problem is that I already have done the changes and don't want to discard them.

Comment: this may not be correct, but see if `git stash` helps. it really depends on the situation

Comment: Not in your scenario, no. GIT doesn't see that you've "moved" the files. It just sees that the content (including the meta data of it's path) has changed. From what I can see there is no way to commit the meta data without the content

Comment: @Dominik either with git stash or no git at all (and just copy paste outside of your repo) if you're not comfortable with the tool: save your changes somehow, then checkout to previous commit, then move again, then commit, then apply the changes.

Comment: If you run `git status -s`, are your files listed with 2 starting letters : `RM file -> moved/file` ? or only one : `R  file -> moved/file` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you moved a bunch of files using `git mv`, then modified those files without runnin `git add` yet :

the staged changes are the renaming without the mofications.

If such is the case : you can run `git commit` straight away.

---

If the `git mv` is easy to reapply (for example: it consists only of `git mv dir1 dir2`), the shortest way is to stash your changes, run the same `git mv` and commit, then pop your changes

```
git stash
git mv [what needs to be renamed]
git commit
git stash pop
```

---

If the `git mv` action is a bit more intricate, another option is :

1. store the output of `git status -s` in a temp file :

   ```
   git status -s > ../renaming.txt
   ```
2. run `git stash`,
3. reapply the list of renames listed in the temp file & commit,
4. run `git stash pop`